# No sound out of headphone jack in 13.04

Tags: 13.04, sound

I installed Ubuntu 13.04 today, finally overriding the Windows 8 Secure Boot after 3 days of trying.

The only issue I am currently having is that there is sound coming from my speakers, but when I plug my headphones in the headphone jack, there is no sound.

What should I do?

Thanks

Comment: Hey, normally this should just work normal. I think it would help to add some info about your laptop (model, brand etc.) and if you can find it some info about your soundboard.

Comment: I encountered a similar problem with my ubuntu installation where it didn't switch to the correct output. Selecting the correct output when the headphones where plugged in solved it for me (as it saved it as the default setting when headphones are plugged in). Alsamixer might fix this as well if I'm to believe my roommate.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that Ubuntu is using your speakers instead of your headphones. To fix this, follow these instructions:

1. Search for `sound` from your `Dash`
2. Open up the Sound Application, it is probably under your Settings
3. Choose the `Output` tab
4. Change your output to your headphones
5. Profit!