# No sound output both speakers and headphone toshiba satellite m55 Xubuntu 12.10

Tags: sound, xubuntu, pulseaudio, headphones

I am running Xubuntu 12.10 and I was trying to repair the sound on the headphone jack since I had sound output through there and now I have no sound what so ever. So I think I made things worst. No sound through the speakers and no sound through the headphone. I know I did something wrong but I don't know what I did. I have pulseaudio. If I could at least get the speakers working again I'll be happy. Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: see this post, this has happened on my toshiba more than once so make a backup of this file http://askubuntu.com/questions/225444/how-to-make-pulseaudio-work-again

Comment: im having the same issue. help please

Answer (score -1):

Try this - Navigate to this menu -  `settings`-> `sound` -> `output`  & try different options under `play sound through`. You can use `Test sound` button to check if choosing any of those options work for you.

Comment: I don't even have the sound option in settings. No icon, nothing! weird?

Comment: In your taskbar, there should be a speaker like icon. Click on it & the last option should be sound settings.

Comment: I tried that already, thanks but no luck. I remember that I killed pulseaudio in the command. How can I un-kill it if that makes sense. Also, when I use mixxx dj mixer software I get sound from that.

Comment: Did u try restarting ur system?

Comment: Yes several time. What do you think about when I entering the command to "pulseaudio -kill". You think that is causing it?

Comment: I don't think so. Coz if it were so, restarting would have solved the issue

Comment: What do you recommend I do?

Comment: Got it fixed! I uninstalled pulseaudio and it works now. But, I still have no sound on headphone jack.

Comment: There seems to be a plenty of posts on similar issues.. Check these out.. 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/132577/no-sound-in-ubuntu-except-at-log-in
http://askubuntu.com/questions/441547/headphone-jack-intermittently-working-on-asus-a55vd-with-ubuntu-13-10
http://askubuntu.com/questions/353838/no-sound-out-of-headphone-jack-in-13-04
http://askubuntu.com/questions/389490/no-sound-from-external-speakers-headphones-jack